# How to filter a json file using angularjs and onclick should display all elements of that

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

Using `angularjs`, I want a search mechanism which should provide a filter based on the Name and Door-No. After applying the filter, I should get a list of the filtered Names and the `onclick` should display the details with respect to the names. The code is given below:

**JSON File**

```
[{"Name": "Isa Andalu", "AC-No-PS-No-SLNo": " 47 - 391 -  455", "Gender": "F", "Age": "37", "Husband-Father": "Sataiah", "EPIC-No": "YZK0922831", "Door-No": "2-11-124/1"},
    {"Name": "A RAJESH", "AC-No-PS-No-SLNo": " 47 - 391 -  456", "Gender": "M", "Age": "18", "Husband-Father": "A SATTAIAH", "EPIC-No": "YZK2535518", "Door-No": "2-11-124/1"},
    {"Name": "BeeraM Venkatreddy", "AC-No-PS-No-SLNo": " 47 - 391 -  458", "Gender": "M", "Age": "33", "Husband-Father": "B Rangareddy", "EPIC-No": "YZK0700815", "Door-No": "2-11-124/2"}
    ]
```

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend lodash(https://lodash.com/docs#filter), there are many useful function to handle js objects, like filter, find can do what you want.